# APC Cache files expire Issue with FastCgi

Tags: php, fastcgi, alternative-php-cache

we have properly installed APC cache on our WHM based server, we have set to expire each file in few hours, but all cached file lost in few seconds.

Our APC Settings:

```
apc.cache_by_default    1

apc.canonicalize    1

apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0

apc.enabled 1

apc.file_md5    0

apc.file_update_protection  2

apc.filters 

apc.gc_ttl  3600

apc.include_once_override   0

apc.lazy_classes    0

apc.lazy_functions  0

apc.max_file_size   10M

apc.mmap_file_mask  

apc.num_files_hint  1000

apc.preload_path    

apc.report_autofilter   0

apc.rfc1867 0

apc.rfc1867_freq    0

apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS

apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_

apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600

apc.serializer  default

apc.shm_segments    1


apc.shm_size    500M

apc.shm_strings_buffer  4M

apc.slam_defense    1

apc.stat    1

apc.stat_ctime  0


apc.ttl 0


apc.use_request_time    1

apc.user_entries_hint   4096

apc.user_ttl    0

apc.write_lock  1
```

Comment: It is because your `apc.ttl` is `0`? Try setting that to a higher number?

Comment: yeh, tried, but still cached files expire in seconds

Comment: How are you establishing the cache has expired? Can you attach what your apc.php shows in terms of caching?

Comment: we have set, 3600 to expire each cached item, we are running FasgCgi +  nginx on centos server.